# Inserting into sql server tables (2016) from json

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some json like this:

```
SET @json =N'[  
       { "id" : 2,"name": "John", "surname": "Smith", "lastname":"", "age": 25 },  

]'
```

I need to insert into table with a condition like `IF LASTNAME IS EMPTY IN JSON THEN INSERT SURNAME INTO LASTNAME ELSE INSERT LASTNAME INTO LASTNAME`

```
insert into mytable (id,firstname,lastname,age)
select id,name,case statement,age from openjson    
WITH (id int 'strict $.id',name nvarchar(100) '$.name',case statement, age int '$.age');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i think this query can respond :

```
DECLARE @json varchar(MAX)
SET @json =N'[  
       { "id" : 2,"name": "John", "surname": "Smith", "lastname":"", "age": 25 },
       { "id" : 2,"name": "John", "surname": "Smith", "lastname":"TT", "age": 25 },
       { "id" : 2,"name": "John", "surname": "Smith", "lastname":"TEST", "age": 25 }
]'  

select id,name,case when lastname = '' then surname else lastname end as lastnameup, age from openjson(@json)    
WITH (id int 'strict $.id',name nvarchar(100) '$.name', surname nvarchar(100) '$.surname', lastname nvarchar(100) '$.lastname', age int '$.age');
```

EDIT for surname propose thanks to @Shnugo

Comment: Good approach (+1 from my side), but the OP wants to use *surname* for a missing *lastname*...